# Problemas con Dependencias en React

Tags: reactjs, npm, plugin, dependencias, babel

Cuando descargo un proyecto de mi repositorio, abro la terminal y instalo(npm install) y me saltan estos avisos:

- **npm WARN deprecated** @babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-numeric-separator instead.
- **npm WARN deprecated** @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-private-methods instead.
- **npm WARN deprecated** @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties instead.
- **npm WARN deprecated** @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator instead.
- **npm WARN deprecated** stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
- **npm WARN deprecated** @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object@7.21.11: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-private-property-in-object instead.
- **npm WARN deprecated** @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining@7.21.0: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining instead.
- **npm WARN deprecated** rollup-plugin-terser@7.0.2: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-terser
- **npm WARN deprecate**d sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
- npm WARN deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
- **npm WARN deprecated** workbox-cacheable-response@6.6.0: workbox-background-sync@6.6.0
- **npm WARNdeprecated** svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.

nose a que se debe estas son mis dependencias

```
 "dependencies": {
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.1",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-datepicker": "^4.21.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-router-dom": "6.17.0",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "react-scroll": "^1.9.0",
        "web-vitals": "^3.5.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.23.2",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.1.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
        "eslint": "^8.52.0",
        "jest": "^29.7.0"
      }
```

he intentado usar `npm install -g npm-check-updates`  `ncu`  `ncu -u`
para ver si actulizo dependencias pero sigue igual.